# Client server application - Best approach in Java

Tags: java, client

Need to create a client server application, both have to communicate with Database. Which approach suitable for this,RMI, Socket programming etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If server communicates with database, I think that client should not (according to layers/tier ideology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture). 
Or if your client works directly with database, than you could avoid usage of server.
For client-server communications you could use a lot of options: RMI, sockets, webservices, etc. 
If you have an experience with java web applications, I suggest to use webservices, if not - RMI.

Comment: I have done some web application using struts1.2.But i am new to web-service. can you tell me that below concept can be done using web-service 1. Server will send a request each client to do a job. Server requesting is happening in manual(say click on submit button). But the client should send a response once the job is done automatically. Can i achieve this using web - service concept?

Comment: Your arcitecture is a bit strange, but could you explain, what clients do you use? Is it a desctop applications, is it possible to run them in application servers etc?

Comment: In my case its a java application, if client machine receives a request from server, it just execute a .bat file which will call that java application.

Comment: In this case you can just use RMI.

Answer (score 1):

When I took my 1st module about client server application in my University, they taught me about RMI & Socket programming. In my opinion, if you want to have basic knowledge about client-server communication, RMI & Socket programming should be useful. However, if you need a solution that you will bring into production system, you should take a look at [EJB](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-1998/jw-10-beans.html) with JSP/JSF.

Comment: In my case the server will send a request to client and client will execute a task and will return status to server when it completes it. More DB operations will be done at server side. In your concept, can client send the response text to server?

Comment: hmmm in client-server concept, normally, the client will send requests to the server. Then the server would do some tasks and send results back to the client. Why does your server need to send requests to client?

Comment: Server is requesting each client to do a Job. Once client is done with that, it should tell to server that  its available for next task to do.Only server knows all information.

Comment: Why tasks are performed at clients, not at server?

Comment: @Palani: to be more closely adhere to client-server concept, a client should be the 1st one to initiate the communication telling the server that they are ready to do tasks. Then your server returns, say a String, stating what job the client needs to do. After finishing the job, the client will call some function of the server to give the results to the server.

Comment: @Dbf Only client machines are having required things for that job like batch file,etc. FYI: Server will allocate no of client for a single job.

Comment: @Dung Tran The UI(application) is present at server machine. Consider it as browsing center approach, a machine will handle all other machines using starting time and ending time.